# Overriding a method in an extended class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following typings:

```
export class CallBuilder<T extends Record> {
    constructor(serverUrl: string)
    call(): Promise<CollectionPage<T>>;
    cursor(cursor: string): this;
    limit(limit: number): this;
    order(direction: 'asc' | 'desc'): this;
    stream(options?: { onmessage?: (record: T) => void, onerror?: (error: Error) => void }): () => void;
}

export interface CollectionPage<T extends Record> {
    records: T[];
    next: () => Promise<CollectionPage<T>>;
    prev: () => Promise<CollectionPage<T>>;
}

export interface Record {
    _links: {
        [key: string]: RecordLink
    };
}
```

And I want to override the call() method from CallBuilder in a different class to bassically have the same functionality, except for the call() return.

```
export class PagedCallBuilder<T extends Record> extends CallBuilder<T> {
    call(): Promise<T>;
}
```

The call() line is giving the following error:

> Property 'call' in type 'PagedCallBuilder' is not assignable to the
>   same property in base type 'CallBuilder'.   Type '() => Promise'
>   is not assignable to type '() => Promise>'.
>       Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise>'.
>         Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'CollectionPage'.
>           Type 'Record' is not assignable to type 'CollectionPage'.
>             Property 'records' is missing in type 'Record'.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of subclassing is that an object of the subclass is compatible with the interface of the superclass, so you can't change method return types arbitrarily.  Instead, consider writing a common superclass that has all the functionality except the `call` method and writing two separate subclasses that each define the `call` method with a different return type.